# How to make hover element inside anchor while hover the whole anchor

Tags: html, css

i have an inline blocked div inside anchor

HTML:

```
<ul>
   <li>
       <a href="">simple
       <div class='bar'>
       </div>
       </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.bar {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
}
.bar:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

I need to get hover effect on div while i hover the anchor, not only div.

Also, my case is a little bit more complicated, so **i cant use something like**

```
a:hover .bar {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Here is jsfiddle with code http://jsfiddle.net/zeL102wr/2/

Comment: do you want to change the background color both div and anchor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like it can't be done in some universal way. only by something like wrapping li to some class and using css

```css
.baz a:hover .foo .hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.baz a:hover .foo .main {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zeL102wr/17/

Since i use LESS, i made a function

```css
.enable-foo-hover() {
&:hover {
    .foo {
        .main {
            opacity: 0;
        }
        .hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
}
}
```

and use it for the element from which i need to hover my construction. Thanks for your answers

Comment: Hi - Please select this as the accepted answer and close the question! :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/zeL102wr/4/

Add a class to your `<a>` tag and use `:hover` on that

Example

**HTML**

```
<a class="hoveranchor" href="">simple
    <div class='bar'>
    </div>
</a>
```

**CSS**

```
.hoveranchor:hover > .bar {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

This would apply the style to all elements with `class="bar"` which are direct descendent of elements with `class="hoveranchor"`

Comment: i wrote in my question, that that is not the option, because i have more complicated markup. Please,see my fiddle for full markup example

Comment: This will not impact any other <a> tags, if there is any other issue please clarify the complication.. will help in understanding your requirement better :)

Answer (score 0):

Updated Css

```
ul li a:hover ,.bar:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3wL6wwsp/)

Comment: i wrote in my question, that that is not the option, because i have more complicated markup. Please,see my fiddle for full markup example

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using jquery the following will work for you 'advanced' list items...

**JQUERY**

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.hoveranchor').mouseover(function (e) {
                console.log($(this).children('.main'));
                $(this).find('.main').addClass('hover');
                $(this).find('.main').removeClass('main');
            });

            $('.hoveranchor').mouseout(function (e) {
                console.log($(this).children('.main'));
                $(this).find('.hover').addClass('main');
                $(this).find('.hover').removeClass('hover');
            });
        });
```

Additionally you will need to:

- add class='hoveranchor' to your anchor tags
- Remove
- Remove css for :hover
- Change opacity of .hover to 1

Check it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/zeL102wr/5/

Comment: yes, this could be an option. I made a LESS mixin for this, which is more suitable for my case

Comment: Cool. Please select any answer or write your own and mark it as answered :)